# Run multiple dummy apps in my integration tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Can I use multiple dummy apps in my integration tests? I want to run some integration tests in one app in some tests in another app.

The reason is that I have a gem that can be run both in a regular Rails app as well as in an engine so I want to test both of those scenarios.

Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

It should be achievable in a straight-forward way. That's standard `test_helper.rb`:

```
# Configure Rails Environment
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] = "test"

require File.expand_path("../../test/dummy/config/environment.rb",  __FILE__)
ActiveRecord::Migrator.migrations_paths = [File.expand_path("../../test/dummy/db/migrate", __FILE__)]
require "rails/test_help"

Rails.backtrace_cleaner.remove_silencers!

# Load support files
Dir["#{File.dirname(__FILE__)}/support/**/*.rb"].each { |f| require f }

# Load fixtures from the engine
if ActiveSupport::TestCase.method_defined?(:fixture_path=)
  ActiveSupport::TestCase.fixture_path = File.expand_path("../fixtures", __FILE__)
end
```

So just create two `test_helper` files:

**test_helper_common.rb**

```
require "rails/test_help"

Rails.backtrace_cleaner.remove_silencers!

# Load support files
Dir["#{File.dirname(__FILE__)}/support/**/*.rb"].each { |f| require f }

# Load fixtures from the engine
if ActiveSupport::TestCase.method_defined?(:fixture_path=)
  ActiveSupport::TestCase.fixture_path = File.expand_path("../fixtures", __FILE__)
end
```

**test_helper_1.rb**

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] = "test"

require File.expand_path("../../test/dummy1/config/environment.rb",  __FILE__)
ActiveRecord::Migrator.migrations_paths = [File.expand_path("../../test/dummy1/db/migrate", __FILE__)]
require __dir__ + 'common'
```

**test_helper_2.rb**

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] = "test"

require File.expand_path("../../test/dummy2/config/environment.rb",  __FILE__)
ActiveRecord::Migrator.migrations_paths = [File.expand_path("../../test/dummy2/db/migrate", __FILE__)]
require __dir__ + '/common'
```

Then just `require 'test_helper_1'` or `require 'test_helper_2'` in your tests.